# Paypal via website database- is this possible?

Tags: php, paypal

Forgive the newbie question.

I'm having a PHP developer build a web app that manages a database of contacts who will need to be paid varying amounts every week.

Is it possible via the PayPal API to click a button within the web app that instantly sends funds to an individual (assuming of course that their paypal address is already in the table)?

Hope I'm asking this right.  Thanks in advance for any tips.

Dave

Comment: you might be looking for [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

Answer (score 1):

yes that's possible. Have them look into the Paypal Payouts API. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts/